# Create a line and circle into visual basic

Tags: excel, vba

I haven't found a correct code to draw a line and a circle.

I have tried with 4 different codes but I have a problem with variables and objects.

Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit  

Private flag As Boolean  

'Variables  
Dim x1 As Single, y1 As Single, x2 As Single, y2 As Single  

'Dibuja el circulo en el formulario  

Private Sub Dibujar_Circulo()        
    Dim cx As Single, cy As Single, dx As Single  
    Dim dy As Single, Radio As Single  

    cx = x1  
    cy = y1  
    dx = x1 - x2  
    dy = y1 - y2  

    ' calcula el radio  
    Radio = Sqr(dx * dx + dy * dy)  

    'Dibuja el círculo  
    Circle (cx, cy), Radio  
End Sub
```

I have obtained just a botton without any action :(

Comment: In Excel?! This is a homework, isn't it? In Excel you can e. g. place a circle shape. Please record a macro while you add an elliptical shape, then you see how the center point and the dimensions can be built.

Comment: `Circle` is an undocumented keyword that was inherited from legacy versions of BASIC. It's not intended to be used. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22986017/undocumented-vba-special-keywords-circle-and-scale)